# "Agree with the writer", but "Agree to/with this answer"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrase-choice

If a someone wrote an answer to a question asked by someone else, and you found the answer given matches your opinion on the points discussed. However, there are little things you do not find right to you.

You don't want to say I disagree with the writer on these points or I almost agree with the author. What you want is to focus on the answer objectively and do not mention the writer.

I know you can say **I agree with someone**, but I wonder if ***I agree with/to this answer***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Agree with" is usually in direct reference to "having the same opinion as someone else".

> I completely agree with what you're saying.
>
> I agree with this answer.

"Agree with" is followed by a **noun**.

"Agree to" is normally in reference to "accepting something proposed by another party"

> I agreed to the deal.
>
> I agreed to accompany her to her car.
>
> I agreed to help him with his homework.

"Agree to" can be followed by a **verb or a noun**.

So in direct answer to your question, "agree with" is the correct option.

Comment: I mostly agree with your answer, I disagree with the part that states "'Agree to' is also accepted, but it's followed by a verb"; though it might be useful for average learners. I believe that the usage "agree with/to" is not that clear-cut. For example, I believe that you wouldn't find these examples sound odd in anyway: *She agreed to our plan*, *If everyone agreed to it, ...*

Comment: Cambridge's dictionary gives this: agree with sth  *phrasal verb*   [ usually in negatives  ] 

to think that something is morally acceptable 
    *I don't agree with hunting.*

Comment: I think [this entry](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/agree-with) from Macmillan is good. What is important for me is that I can say "I agree with this answer" so +1 for the answer. However, the answer could be improved for other readers.

Comment: These examples taken from Cambridge's dictionary. If you could use them to improve your answer as I have not reached the level of feeling it!: The company agreed to the settlement to avoid the expense of a lengthy legal case. | Club members have provisionally agreed to the changes.| I should never have agreed to her appointment.| We had to push them to agree to our terms, but they finally did accept the deal.| They are unlikely to agree to these plans unless the cost is reduced.

Comment: Check out my above edit.

Comment: Your edit is good.  Why not bring the rest of the answer in line with what you've added?